# I am trying to do abstract screening by metagear package and giving error:

Tags: r

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘metagear’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘stringi’

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install the `stringi` package:

```
install.packages('stringi')
```